# Vue.js using two routers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my main router I'm using general names for each route, for example

```
{
path: '/:locale/:id',
name: 'mainNavigation',
},
```

However `mainNagivation` contains multiple other paths inside, according to however many `:id`s there are, and when I use google analytics, like :

```
Vue.use(
VueGtag,
{
    config: { id: 'G-******' }
},
router
)
```

I'm getting only `mainNavigation` but I need to show the specific names of each path. So I was thinking about creating another more detailed `router` just for Google Analytics, with more specified paths and names. Can something like that work? Can I use multiple routers?

I did try creating another `router`, named it `router2` and passed it to Google Analytics however it wasn't capturing anything.

Answer (score 1):

create file mainRouter

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import interface one from 'interface one'
import interface two from 'interface two'

var allRoutes: any[] = []
const routes = allRoutes.concat(interface one, interface two)

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: routes
});
```

and create file interface one

```
import adminHome from 'adminHome'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: adminHome
   },

  ]

 export default routes
```

and create file interface two

```
import SupervisorsHome from 'SupervisorsHome'
const routes = [
{
  path: '/supervisors/home',
  name: 'home',
  component: SupervisorsHome
},
]

  export default routes
```